# Как кастомизировать Results View в ICollectionView?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Возможно ли как нибудь кастомизировать Results View в ICollectionView ?

Сейчас у меня есть так

```
public ICollectionView PersonsView
{
    get
    {
        source = new CollectionViewSource();
        source.Source = parent.Persons;

        return source.View;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Позже я этим заполняю ComboBox ( `ItemsSource="{Binding Data.PersonsView}"` ).

Все работает, но мне нужно, что бы отображалось в `ComboBox` - **имя** и **фамилия** к примеру, а сейчас отображается только **имя**.

Как мне можно это сделать ?

Comment: покажите какими данными вы заполняете Combobox и еще xaml разметку

Comment: @S.Kost добавил !

Comment: попробуйте теперь убрать свойство DisplayMember

Comment: @S.Kost безрезультатно. так как и было (

Comment: судя по вашему шаблону, у вас показывается не только имя, а еще и ID. Это так?

Comment: @S.Kost id показывает только тогда, когда я выберу ComboBox (ну то есть нажму на него). А мне надо что бы оно всегда показывалось. То есть. Вижу комбобокс - в нем есть только имя. Нажимаю на него - показывается все как надо, выбираю нужное - комбобокс закрывается и я вижу только имя без id.

Comment: я вас понял, это достигается переопределением ToString() или же создайте свойство которое объединяет все данные которые вам необходимы и у ComboBox указать имя этого свойства в DisplayMemberPath. Попробуйте сказанное, используя стандартный ComboBox

Comment: @S.Kost сейчас попробую !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переопределите метод `ToString()` в классе `Person`

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, soName); 
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогло =(

Comment: Спасибо большое ! 
Суть Вашего ответа была верна ) немного другое переопределил и все заработало =)